Error "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2" after upgrade Java and eclipse
I upgraded to Eclipse 2024-06. This version requires Java 21, I also upgrade to Java 21.
When restarting Eclipse, workspace was upgraded to latest upgrade.
Now I got the error:
org.openjfx:javafx-controls:jar:${javafx.platform}:22.0.1 was not found in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 in pom.xml
Environment is:

Windows 10
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, 2024-06 (4.32.0)
Java Temurin-21.0.3+9 (build 21.0.3+9-LTS)
Apache Maven 3.9.2

Just upgrading Eclipse on Windows and Java after an online warning. No code change. Now cannot compile project anymore due to Maven dependencies errors.
pom.xml:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>root</groupId>
    <artifactId>osmart_mv</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>21</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>21</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
    
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.openjfx/javafx-controls -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>22.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- LOMBOK -->
        <!-- check latest version at: https://projectlombok.org/features/ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.30</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- SQLite -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.45.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Log4J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.22.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Apache POI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jxls</groupId>
          <artifactId>jxls-jexcel</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastexcel-reader</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.dhatim</groupId>
            <artifactId>fastexcel</artifactId>
            <version>0.16.6</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- FeishuAPI -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.larksuite.oapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>oapi-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
        
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>21</source>
                    <target>21</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running -->
                        <!-- Usage: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>root.osmart_mv.App</mainClass>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>root.osmart_mv.App</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
</project>


Starting a new Maven project in Eclipse works with not error. Plugin version is 11.0.2. Changing version work until 16. But from 17 is shows the same error.

It is recommended to use the Java that is shipped with Eclipse to run Eclipse which is Java 21 for Eclipse 2024-06. In your project you can use the same Java or(!) any JDK/JRE of the same or other Java version that you have installed on your system and configured in your preferences Java > Installed JREs. Please provide a minimal reproducible example that proves what you are saying (that the issue is caused by upgrading Java and(!) Eclipse).

same issue, running on openjdk-21. And you might also be interested know, that the issue has already confirmed by maven developers. So this is actually a fully legitimate issue. Do your research howlger (but I guess your title fits)! https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-8131
